# Laravel deleting cache working in controller but not in model closure

Tags: laravel

I'd like to delete a specific model from the cache using its id. This works as expected in the controller, but not using the model closure.

What I have in `App\Models\Post`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

protected static function booted()
{
    static::updated(function ($post) {
        Cache::forget('post:'.$post->id);
    });
}
```

If I do `Cache::forget('post:'.$post->id);` in the controller it works.

Something I'm missing?

Comment: How are you updating the model?

Comment: The Post model is passed to the method, like `updatePost(Post $post)` and then it's updated using `$post->property = 'example'; $post->save();`. According to the Laravel docs using `save()` triggers the updated event

Comment: So if you add `Log::info('triggered')` in the `static::updated` callback, you see a log file entry?

Comment: Maaaaaaaybbeeeee... Ehm no. Good point. I'll dig into why it's not triggered.

Comment: From the docs: If a model already existed in the database and the save method is called, the updating / updated events will fire.

Comment: Are you actually changing anything in the post? The `updated` event only triggers when the model was dirty, i.e. something actually changed, as you can see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L805).

Comment: I did not... When I use the `saved` event it does work, even when the model is not dirty. This is useful as I can then still clear the cache without actually changing something. @Remul feel free to post an answer.

Comment: Meh, I'm just too deep in assumptions that if you expect an `updated` event, you actually changed something :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are actually changing a value on your model, because the `updated` event only fires when the model was dirty, as you can see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L805).

The `saved` event however will fire whenever you call the `save()` method, as you can see [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L769):

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::saved(function ($post) {
        Cache::forget('post:'.$post->id);
    });
}
```

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#events):

> The `retrieved` event will fire when an existing model is retrieved from
> the database. When a new model is saved for the first time, the
> `creating` and `created` events will fire. If a model already existed in
> the database and the save method is called, the `updating` / `updated`
> events will fire. However, in both cases, the `saving` / `saved` events
> will fire.

Comment: Thanks. I will check how I can submit a suggestion to update the docs, as from these docs it's unclear that `update`/`updated` are not fired when the model is not dirty.